# Git: Best strategy to create repos

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git and I am not sure what strategy fits best for my 1st project with it.

e.g.

```
/src
    /base/forms
    /base//masks
    /base/logics
    /base/communication
    /prj/A
    /prj/B
    /prj/C
```

src is a software. It is in use in 3 projects (A, B, C). Every project is a bit different. But the difference is all handled in the code of /prj/X. The codes of /base are the same.

Now it can be possibe that I need to update a base-module (e.g. forms) but just for prj B. And some weeks later it will be for every prj.

Whats the best way to organize my git?

One big repo with anythink in it (src)?

Or a repo per section (base/prj)?

Or a repo per dir (base/form, base/mask, ... prj/A, prj/B, ...)?

Think to answer I would need a bit of experience with git but as I already said I am new to it.

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using one repo for each specific version and one repo for the base objects.

In each specific repo, I'd use a submodule to pull in the base project. This will allow you to tightly control 'which version' of the base module gets pulled in for each specific module.

Examples

```
forms
---A---B---C---D
masks
---X---Y---Z    

/prj/A
---Q---W---E---R
with
/prj/A/base/forms
---A---B---C
/prj/A/base/masks
---X---Y


/prj/B
---B---N---M
with
/prj/B/base/forms
---A---B
/prj/B/base/masks
---X---Y---Z
```

Having this 'structure' will allow you to checkout different commits for each submodule yet move them up as each one is able to. Each configuration will be self-documented in code with what version it is currently using of each base project.

might even be worth having a top level src project w/ submodules of each /prj/ project so that you have an over all 'this works with this' version history

such as

```
/src HEAD
master A---B---C
/src/prj/A Q---W---E
/src/prj/B B---N

then possibly
/src 
master A---B---C---D
/src/prj/A Q---W---E
/src/prj/B B---N---M

then possibly

/src 
master A---B---C---D---E
/src/prj/A Q---W---E---R
/src/prj/B B---N---M
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using, but it appears you should use a git repo for each of your 3 individual projects + one repo for the common base code.

Then you just import that common code into each one of the individual projects. You could import particular versions of it, in case you need to introduce changes for just one of them